# kendo UI grid datasource asp webforms

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, kendo-ui

So I followed the example that [Kendo Provides](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/local-data.html) to use an external Data Source , for some reason when you put a URL of Default.aspx/GetEvents  (Where GetEvents is a webmethod in Default.aspx) it returns the entire HTML of Default.aspx instead of just calling the webmethod in a normal AJAX call.

So I found a way around that and I use the local data source method , which calls a javascript function - this javascript function does its own ajax call to my webmethod in default.aspx and gets a successfull response

so here is my code

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                    dataSource: {
                        data: createRandomData(),
                        schema: {
                            data: "d"
                        },
                        pageSize: 10
                    },
                    height: 250,
                    scrollable: true,
                    sortable: true,
                    filterable: true,
                    pageable: {
                        input: true,
                        numeric: false
                    },
                    columns: [
                        {
                            field: "Title",
                            title: "Title",
                            width: 100
                        },
                        {
                            field: "StartDate",
                            title: "StartDate",
                            width: 100
                        },
                        {
                            field: "Keywords",
                            width: 100
                        }
                    ]
                });
            });
```

Here is the begining of what createRandomData() is returning - it's valid json - I just don't want to paste it all and make this question un-readable

```
"d" : [
{
    "Title": "Chicago BlackHawks vs. Detroit Redwings",
    "StartDate": "9/7/2012 12:00:00 AM",
    "Keywords": "-- Select --"
},
{
    "Title": "",
    "StartDate": "1/1/1900 12:00:00 AM",
    "Keywords": "-- Select --"
}, .......
```

I see no reason why this would not be working , right now the grid just says "loading..." and stays like that for ever , no console errors

```
                    function createRandomData() {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "MyEvents.aspx/GetEvents",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (msg) {                                
                            var rs = msg;
                            return rs;
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The likely problem is that KendoUI expects a simple javascript call (without AJAX) when using the `data` element.  When you call the JS method it returns right away, but AJAX call takes a little bit longer to finish, but Kendo grid never gets notified when the call is done.

What you could try instead is using the `transport.read` object on the dataSource [here](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#transportread-objectstringfunction).  This way the grid should work fine with the AJAX call.

EDIT:
Have you tried something like this:

```
dataSource: {
    transport: {
        read: function(options) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "MyEvents.aspx/GetEvents",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {                                
                    options.success(msg.d);
                }
            });
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: I had it like that, the problem is when I use url: ".."  and connect to a webmethod it is not calling my webmethod - it is returning the entire aspx page , like the kendo grid doesn't know how to make ajax  call - all it does it request the aspx page - weird , never seen anything like that before

Comment: I could , but I am positive its returning the sample I provided

Comment: posted code , see how I had to make the ajax call in another function ? because putting that in url was not working

Comment: See if using the code like my example would work.  This basically works exactly like your previous JS function, but in the `success` handler you're letting Kendo know that the data is ready.  Note that I removed your `schema` definition as well since I'm already returing the `d` portion in t he `success` handler.

Comment: sorry I didnt get back sooner  , this is still not working ,  the grid is showing up with no data in it , in firebug I see the requeset to GetEvents and the successfull response - i have no idea whats going on

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps change your schema defintion:

from this

```
schema: {
 data: "d"
}
```

to this

```
schema: {
 model: {
  fields: {
    Title: { type: "string" },
    StartDate: { type: "string" },
    Keywords: { type: "string" }
   }
 }
}
```